# Multually exlcusive + indpedent random variable?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Two events can't be both multually exclusive and independent at the same time. However, I have one question regarding the following problem:

"Let $X$ be the number of even tosses and $Y$ the number of 3's that occur in $n$ rolls of a fair die. Compute Cov$(X,Y)$ (you can ignore this part)"

I am thinking that one roll can't get you both even and a 3 at the same time. That means X and Y are multually exclusive. Furthermore, $X\sim B(p=1/2, n)$       ,  $Y\sim B(p=1/6,n)$, if $X=n$, then $Y$ can't be $n$. So this also implies they are mutually exclusive and not independent. How come the solution says $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: I don't think X and Y are independent. For instance, if I tell you that all tosses were even, you know for sure that Y=0. I also have never heard that "events can't be both mutually exclusive and independent".

Comment: The "empty" event $A$ and any event $B$ are mutually exclusive and independent. It is not clear what you might mean by your random variables are mutually exclusive. Random variables are not events. And you can certainly have, for example, $2$ $3$'s and $2$ even in $5$ tosses.

Comment: @elexhobby, I agree with you that X and Y are dependent.  As for the "events can't be both mutually exclusive and independent" I only know the case for "event" (P(A|B)=P(A and B)/P(B)), this will be equal P(A) if indepedent. But if A and B are mutually exclusive, then P(A|B)=0/P(B)=0, which is not equal to P(A).

Comment: @AndréNicolas, yes, I mix up the concept between event and random variable.   Because we learnt event earlier, at that time, we talked about mutually exclusive event. I am not sure if we can apply the same concept to random variable

Comment: @AndréNicolas, do you think that X and Y are independent? the total toss is n. if X=n, then Y must be 0.

Comment: The random variables $X$ and $Y$ as defined in your post are not independent.